# A better way to pass along promise callback methods

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I see myself passing the resolve and reject a methods a lot:

```
function createChangeRequest(contactId) {
        return $q(function (resolve, reject) {
            parseAPI.runCloud('createChangeRequest', {contactId: contactId}, resolve, reject);
        });

    }
```

And then call them in the target function:

```
function runCloud(methodName, params, resolve, reject) {
        Parse.Cloud.run(methodName, params, {
            success: function (response) {
                // obtained secret string
                console.log(methodName + ' response -> ', response);
                resolve(response);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                // error
                console.log(methodName + ' error -> ', error);
                reject(error);
            }
        });
    }
```

It solves my need for working with different promises syntaxes. I have a feeling there is a better way. Is there?

And will it support advanced flows:

```
function updateItem(itemId, className, json, resolve, reject) {

        return getItem(className, itemId).then(function (item) {

            return saveItem(item, json);

        });
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not manually create and resolve new promises. [Parse.cloud.run](https://parse.com/docs/js/api/classes/Parse.Cloud.html#methods_run) already returns a promise object so you should really organize you code in a simpler manner. Something like this:

```
function createChangeRequest(contactId) {
  return parseAPI.runCloud('createChangeRequest', {contactId: contactId}).then(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function() {
    console.log('Error ocurred');
  });
}

function runCloud(methodName, params, resolve, reject) {
  return Parse.Cloud.run(methodName, params);
}
```

Comment: It looks better. Will it work in the advanced case I've added to the question?

Comment: I'm not sure how you are going to use updateItem with `createChangeRequest` but promises chaining will work just perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to isolate other promise syntaxes as much as possible by 'converting' them to `$q` promises. Then use regular `$q` syntax anywhere else. In your case, assuming Parse.Cloud works with explicit callbacks, I would do this:

```
function runCloud(methodName, params) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    Parse.Cloud.run(methodName, params, {
        success: function (response) {
            // obtained secret string
            console.log(methodName + ' response -> ', response);
            deferred.resolve(response);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            // error
            console.log(methodName + ' error -> ', error);
            deferred.reject(error);
        }
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Then, in all users of the `runCloud` function, you can switch to regular `$q` syntax like this:

```
function createChangeRequest(contactId) {
    parseAPI.runCloud('createChangeRequest', {contactId: contactId}).then(function(result){
        //do something with result
    });
}
```

Comment: I used to work with deferred. They must serve a purpose. But recently I moved to this syntax:

return $q(function (resolve, reject) {... }); It saves the need to declare a deferred object while in the q library allows you to add a third callback (notify).